# Pointers as Function Parameters Example

Tags: pointers, return

I am have difficulties in a problem where it asks to compare two integers and return a pointer to the smallest one. This should be easy enough but I think my misunderstanding is a confusion of the pointer address and content. The question is as follows:
(Consider a function with this prototype):
    int *smaller( int *ptr l, int *ptr2);
(2 marks)

(The "smaller" function compares two integers and returns a pointer to the smallest one.
Fill in the blanks to complete the following program):
    #include 
    int *smaller (int *ptrl, int *ptr2);
    int main()
    { int a; int b; int *p;
    scanf(" %d%d ",&a, &b);
    -------- - smaller (------ , ------ );
    return O;
    }
    int *smaller ( ------ , -------)
    { if ( ------- ) return ------ ;
    else return ------- ;
    }

Here is the code I have come up with:

## include

```
int *smaller(int *ptr1, int *ptr2);
int main()
{
    int a; int b; int * p;
    printf("Enter the first digit:");
    scanf("%d", &a);
    printf("Enter the seconddigit:");
    scanf("%d", &b);
    p = smaller(&a,&b);
    printf("The smaller digit is %d\n\n", *p);
    return 0;
}
int *smaller( int *ptr1, int *ptr2)
{
    if (ptr1 <  ptr2)
    {
        return ptr1;
    }
     else
     {
       return ptr2;
    }

 }
```

It outputs that the smallest integer is the second number that is entered, regardless of the size.

Answer (score 0):

I figured the problem momentarily after posting, I had to put the * (content) sign in the if and else statement.